# how to navigate from one route to other route in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I navigate to another route in Reactjs

I have a route for example : **http://localhost:3000/product/men's-clothing/Fjallraven--Foldsack-No-1-Backpack-Fits-15-Laptops/6098e4215613e83018695afc**
and I want to navigate to another route for example **http://localhost:3000/cart**

If I use react-router-dom, I am getting new route as **http://localhost:3000/product/men's-clothing/Fjallraven--Foldsack-No-1-Backpack-Fits-15-Laptops/cart** but it should be **http://localhost:3000/cart**

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
        <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} exact />
        <Route
          path="/product/:category/:title/:id"
          component={ProductDetail}
          exact
        />
      </main>
      <Footer pathName={window.location.pathname} />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: How do you change the route to "/cart" from `ProductDetail` component?

Comment: I have a button for cart and If I navigate from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/cart  working fine but if I navigate from http://localhost:3000/product/men's-clothing/Fjallraven--Foldsack-No-1-Backpack-Fits-15-Laptops/6098e4215613e83018695afc to localhost:3000/cart I am not getting exact url

Comment: Share the code that executes when you click the button to navigate to "/carT"